# PHP : edit database driven content

Tags: php, html, mysqli

in my website i am fetching `about.php` content from database like this

```
$query= mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM about");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)):?>
<p><?php echo $row['content']?></p>
<p><strong>Projects Completed :  </strong><?php echo  row['projects_completed']?></p>
```

Now there is an edit button  to edit page content

```
<a  class="btn btn-default pull-right" href="about-us.php?edit" name="edit">Edit</a>
```

what i want when someone presses edit button same content should be shown in text fields and a submit button , for this should i use includes ? i mean in the beginning i include a file that fetches content and then on button click i include a file that shows content in editable mode , is that right approach ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for the appropriate query string (and authority to edit) and either display the content or display the content in a texture with button to submit.

```
if (isset($_GET['page']) && [your authority to edit check]) {
    echo '<textarea>'.$row['content'].'</textarea>';
} else {
    echo $row['content'];
}
```

Comment: that seems smart let me try

Comment: are you sure this is perfect answer i mean is it good as per best practices ?

Comment: I think best practice would be to use javascript to modify the DOM and AJAX to submit changes to PHP, but in terms of an only PHP solution, I think this is pretty good. Just make sure your authority check is solid.